# Crushing drink cans

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have a 15 pound weight that I use to crush 8.4 oz red bull cans. A metal barbell with a handle and 2 ends. Not 100% flat ends, but close to flat. About 12 inches from end to end.

I hold the barbell by one end and lower it to crush a standing redbull can. sometimes the can crushes completely, other times it gets crooked. There doesn't seem to be much predictability in regards the various methods of striking it. Only that multiple small strikes allows it to be mended and crushed by hand also.

So, my question is - how can I predictable crush the can with the least effort? I think my strikes are consistent but the cans are in need of some pre-crushing to create fault lines were it will crash like a controlled demolition, or at least that is my current theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a very slight wobble of the weight as it went from "standing" to "dropping". The standing position had no wobble, but it created a wobble when released. The solution was hold the weight freely and to control the wobble, so when allowed to drop by gravity, no additional forces occur in transition. Can crushes are then relatively predictable. Only it hurts my back a little from the extra forces and time.

Comment: "Only it hurts my back a little from the extra forces and time." Wow that sounds like a lot of Red Bull.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, no, you can't predict exactly how the can will crush. There are too many variables in the manufacturing of the can and the crushing force. This is typical in most buckling problems. There are many "modes" (shapes) that the structure can fail in.

The uncertainty of how the can can crush can be reduced by adding a failure point (dent) in the can. This will concentrate the force on that point and almost certainly guarantee where the the can will fail. It will also greatly reduce the force required to crush the can.

Another thing that will help is to make something that will hold the base of the can in one position. A slightly larger can that is cut down to only cover the base will keep the base from moving.  This will keep the can from sliding to the side while force is being applied to it. A typical cause of incompletely crushed cans is that they are pushed out from under the weight because the top doesn't stay parallel to the base.

Comment: That sounds likely about the bottom, but that seems to indicate a bad strike. As for the dent, my experience with this so far is that causes the situation to be even more unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

Firstly, you're assuming every can is made identically to each other. There may be slight differences in how some cans are made which alters the strength and crushing characteristics of the cans.

Secondly, to increase the reliability of crushing results you need the same perfect alignment between can and the crushing weight.

Thirdly, the action of the crushing weight, how it strikes each can needs to be exactly the same when crushing cans.

I have the impression your system for crushing the cans is manual. Such a system can introduce all types of random fluctuations which results in different crushing outcomes.

A well designed and made automated system will have fewer random fluctuations and produce more consistent results.